# Why is this Linked list code result in always head being null?

Tags: c, linked-list

I have implemented a short linked list code to add to the beginning of the list.

However the head always contained `NULL`. I really couldn't get why its behaving in this way. Any help is appreciated ! Below is the code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int iData;
    struct node *next;
} Node;

void add2Beg(Node* head, int num);


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    Node *head = NULL;
    add2Beg(head, 5);
    if (head == NULL)
        printf("nothing in head !!!\n");
else{
    printf("not null\n");
}
    add2Beg(head, 15);
    return 0;
}

//adds to the beginning of the linked list
void add2Beg(Node* head, int num)
{
    //create a temporary location to hold the new entry
    Node* temp = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    temp->iData = num;

    if(head == NULL)
    {
        head = temp;
        printf("inside add2Beg\n");
        printf("%d\n", head->iData);
        head->next = NULL;
        printf("exiting add2Beg\n");
    }
    else
    {
        temp->next = head;
        printf("%p\n", temp->next);
        head = temp;
    }

}
```

Comment: I've fixed your formatting. For future reference, try to avoid pasting tabs into the code-blocks. They almost always screw up the spacing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you never assigned head to anything other than NULL...

```
//here you set it to NULL then pass it to your function
Node *head = NULL; 
add2Beg(head, 5);
```

here in your function you pass in a copy of "head"

```
void add2Beg(Node* head, int num)   
{
   //create a temporary location to hold the new entry   
    Node* temp = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));   
    temp->iData = num;      
    if(head == NULL)     //we'll get in here
```

At this point you assign temp to it, so within the scope of this function it's something vaid, but once you leave this function it's back to NULL.

You passed in a **copy** of the pointer "head" and called it "head". You need to either return the value and assign it in `main()` or pass a pointer to head into this function in order for the value to be updated.

Solutions:

```
Node *head = NULL; 
head = add2Beg(head, 5);

Node* add2Beg(Node* head, int num){
    ...
    return head;
```

OR

```
Node *head = NULL; 
add2Beg(&head, 5);

void add2Beg(Node** head, int num){
    ...
```

Answer (score 6):

Because the `head` variable inside of `add2Beg()` is local to that function.  Assigning a new pointer value to it (`head = temp;`) only changes the `head` variable *inside* the function.  You need to pass in a pointer-to-pointer:

```
void add2Beg(Node** head, int num)
```

Then use `*head` inside the function:

```
if(*head == NULL)
{
    *head = temp;
```

Be careful about lines like `head->next = NULL;` -- this should be rewritten as `(*head)->next = NULL;` or `(**head).next = NULL;`.

And so on.  Then call the function like so:

```
add2Beg(&head, 15);
```

Comment: duh ! these pointers !  Thanks for pointing out the mistake :)

Answer (score 1):

Your function add2beg is not returning the new head in the case when it's modified.  Change your function to:

```
Node * add2Beg(Node* head, int num)
```

and return the head at the end:

```
return head;
```

Comment: Thanks ! i think this way of implementing is easier than using pointer-to-pointer method suggested by @cdhowie